# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

this code is error ...

```
$simpan = mysql_query("insert into siswa (nama, jk, nis, nisn, nik, sebagai, tgl_masuk, kelas, jurusan, tempat_lahir,
tgl_lahir, agama, kwn, butuh_khusus, jalan, rt, rw, dusun, kelurahan, kecamatan,
kode_pos, tinggal, transportasi, telp_rumah, hp, email, kps, nama_ayah, tl_ayah, pendidikan_ayah, 
pekerjaan_ayah, penghasilan_ayah, kebutuhan_ayah, nama_ibu, tl_ibu, pendidikan_ibu, pekerjaan_ibu, penghasilan_ibu, kebutuhan,ibu, nama_wali, 
tl_wali, pendidikan_wali, pekerjaan_wali, penghasilan_wali, kebutuhan_wali )values('$nama', '$jk', '$nis', '$nisn', '$nik', '$sebagai', '$tgl_masuk', '$kelas', '$jurusan', '$tempat_lahir', 
'$tgl_lahir', '$agama', '$kwn', '$butuh_khusus', '$jalan', '$rt', '$rw', '$dusun', '$kelurahan', '$kecamatan', 
'$kode_pos', '$tinggal', '$transportasi', '$telp_rumah', '$hp', '$email', '$kps', '$nama_ayah', '$tl_ayah', '$pendidikan_ayah', 
'$pekerjaan_ayah', '$penghasilan_ayah', '$kebutuhan_ayah', '$nama_ibu', '$tl_ibu', '$pendidikan_ibu', '$pekerjaan_ibu', '$penghasilan_ibu', '$kebutuhan_ibu', '$nama_wali', 
'$tl_wali', '$pendidikan_wali', '$pekerjaan_wali', '$penghasilan_wali', '$kebutuhan_wali')")or die (mysql_error());
```

am I missing something here ?

Comment: You must improve your question to make other understand then only you will get a good and quick answer.

Comment: echo out $simpan and then copy and paste it into phpmyadmin in the sql tab and see what you get for an answer. That will put you on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an error with your database. Your actual code apears to be fine (assuming all of the variables are already defined and there are no logic errors)
Double check that all of the columns are defined in your MySQL table `siswa`.

Also, the MySQL functions in PHP are out dated and it is recomended that you use mysqli. Here is a link on how to query using this method: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Another way to test if there is an issue is by testing the query manually (inserting the query string streight into the mysql console)

To summarise, *this is not an issue with PHP*, your column structure of your database does not match the number of inputs you provided.